# Solana - SolPlay issues within Uniity

Tags: web3.js, solana-sdk

I have several of the below errors and I cannot figure out how to fix this. Is anyone able to assist me?

Failed to extract Solana.Unity.Rpc.Converters.TransactionErrorJsonConverter class of base type Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter`1<Solana.Unity.Rpc.Models.TransactionError> when inspecting Packages/com.solana.unity_sdk/Packages/Solana.Unity.Rpc.dll
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper:ExtractAllClassesThatAreUserExtendedScripts (string,string[]&,string[]&,string[]&)

Comment: Hey which unity sdk version are you using?

Comment: 0.0.6 is the version I see in Unity

Comment: So the recent changes in phantom broke the phantom connection in webgl. You would need to update the unity sdk version and use the WalletAdapter wallet for that to work again. Here is a game example using SolPlay with the newest UnitySDK version. https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-starter-kits/tree/main/seven-seas Maybe ask in the UnitySDK repo here: https://github.com/magicblock-labs/Solana.Unity-SDK since SolPlay is currently incompatible.